# NodeJS - Get data from asynchonous function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I'm using request module in nodejs to drawl data from some website.

```
let asyncFunction = () => {
    let listWeb = ['https://www.npmjs.com/package/request', 'https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio']
    let promiseArray = []

    listWeb.forEach(async element => {
        await requestpromise({
            url: element,
            method: "GET",
            proxy: "http://sacombank%5Cdatnq29692%3ASatureday%40123@192.168.95.100:3128",
            strictSSL: false,
            //resolveWithFullResponse: true
        })
        .then(res => {
            let $ = cheerio.load(res);
            let name = $('#top > div.w-100.ph0-l.ph3.ph4-m > h2 > span');

            name.each((ind, ele) => {
                console.log(ele.attribs.title);
                promiseArray.push(ele.attribs.title);
            });
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    })

    console.log(promiseArray);
}

asyncFunction()
```

the result which i wanna see from the terminal is:

```
['request','cheerio']
```

but the response also like:

```
[]
request
cheerio
```

Could you guys please help fix it and explain about async and await function and what wrong with my code?
Many thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to the asynchronous world of Javascript and http requests in node.js.  Except in very certain cases, asynchronous operations in Javascript are non-blocking and do NOT stop the flow of your code.  The code keeps going while the asynchronous operations run in the background.  In this specific function that means that your `.forEach()` loop does not wait for the `await` to finish (because `.forEach()` is not promise-aware).

And, your function returns BEFORE either of the `await requestpromise()` operations have completed (that's why you get `[]` in your log first).  So, you can't look at the result there as the result hasn't been computed yet.

You can fix things by making a couple of changes.  Since your requests are independent, you can run them in parallel and use `Promise.all()` to both tell you when they are both done and to collect the results in order.  This should also run a little faster than attempting to do the operations one at a time.

```
let asyncFunction = () => {
    let listWeb = ['https://www.npmjs.com/package/request', 'https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio']

    return Promise.all(listWeb.map(element => {
        return requestpromise({
            url: element,
            method: "GET",
            proxy: "http://sacombank%5Cdatnq29692%3ASatureday%40123@192.168.95.100:3128",
            strictSSL: false,
            //resolveWithFullResponse: true
        }).then(res => {
            let $ = cheerio.load(res);
            let name = $('#top > div.w-100.ph0-l.ph3.ph4-m > h2 > span');

            // get an array of title values and make that the resolved value
            // of this promise
            return name.map((ind, ele) => {
                return ele.attribs.title;
            }).get();
        })
    })).then(results => {
        console.log(results.flat());
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    })
}

asyncFunction();
```

---

If you wanted to sequence the two operations, then you need to replace the `.forEach()` with a regular `for` statement.  `for` is built to pause for `await`.  `.forEach()` is not built to pause for `await` in its callback.  That could look like this:

```
let asyncFunction = async () => {
    let listWeb = ['https://www.npmjs.com/package/request', 'https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio']
    let results = [];

    try {
        for (let element of listWeb) {
            let res = await requestpromise({
                url: element,
                method: "GET",
                proxy: "http://sacombank%5Cdatnq29692%3ASatureday%40123@192.168.95.100:3128",
                strictSSL: false,
                //resolveWithFullResponse: true
            });
            let $ = cheerio.load(res);
            let name = $('#top > div.w-100.ph0-l.ph3.ph4-m > h2 > span');

            name.each((ind, ele) => {
                results.push(ele.attribs.title);
            });
        }
        console.log(results);
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}


asyncFunction()
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, i'm understand about `for` and `forEach()` but i get confused about `Promise.all()`, i didn't see any `await` function, so how the program understand and await to get the result from all requestpromise. i was try to use Promise but always got `Promise {pending}`

Comment: @NguyenQuocDat - The first implementation doesn't use `await`.  It runs both operations in parallel and feeds the promises returned by `requestpromise()` into `Promise.all()` so that `Promise.all().then().catch()` tells you when it's done.  The second implementation does use `await` to sequence your two requests one after the other.

Comment: @NguyenQuocDat - If you're getting `Promise {pending}` that just means that you're looking at a promise.  To get the resolved value out of a promise, you must either use `.then()` or `await` on the promise.  Or, to get the results out of an array of promises, you can use `Promise.all().then()`.

Comment: That mean `Promise.all()` execute all `requestpromise()` almost at the same time while `for` run `requestpromise()` one by one ??

Comment: @NguyenQuocDat - Yes.  The `Promise.all()` implementation fires off all the `requestpromise()` requests and then waits for all the responses to come back.  The `await` implementation fires the first request, waits for its response, then fires the second request and waits for its response.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `for` loop instead of `forEach` function, like this:

```js
// add "async" keyword to this function
let asyncFunction = async () = > {
    let listWeb = ['https://www.npmjs.com/package/request', 
                   'https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio']
    let promiseArray = [];

    for (let element of listWeb) {
        let res = await requestpromise({
            url: element,
            method: "GET",
            proxy: "http://sacombank%5Cdatnq29692%3ASatureday%40123@192.168.95.100:3128",
            strictSSL: false,
            //resolveWithFullResponse: true
        });
        
        let $ = cheerio.load(res);
        let name = $('#top > div.w-100.ph0-l.ph3.ph4-m > h2 > span');

        name.each((ind, ele) = > {
            console.log(ele.attribs.title);
            promiseArray.push(ele.attribs.title);
        });
    }

    console.log(promiseArray);
}

asyncFunction();
```

Comment: Cảm ơn người anh em, giờ thì mình hiểu rồi, theo như câu trả lời của bác jfriend00 bên dưới thì thằng for sẽ có hàm pause để chờ xử lý các hàm await trong khi thằng forEach thì không có :D